# Separate Azure VM's by using subnetmask on the Windows cliënt network interface

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, subnet

Can I put all my Windows VM's in one Azure Subnet and then separate them by using the Subnetmask on the cliënt OS.
And use that way to group them for different customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can. But why would you? Putting them into different Azure subnets gives you much better network segregation and things like ARM templates or scripting makes it pretty easy to roll out a whole collection of subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make any changes to the internal network configuration inside your VMs when running in Azure, this is likely to break connectivity.

You are better off putting them on different subnets. This then gives you the benefit of NSG's to control access between subnets.